# Convert string elements of a list into variables

Tags: python, string, list, variables

I got a list

```
v = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and i want to turn into

```
v = [a, b, c]
```

to use the entries as variables. I know that eval() and exec() are not recommended. How can i  solve that instead?

Comment: Why not use variables in the first place?

Comment: It's not that eval/exec are bad, it's that needing them in your program might indicate poor design choices.

Comment: it is bad practice to do this. If you want to map `a, b, c` to something else, use a dictionary. That said, see the post by flyingmeatball if you still want to do it

Answer (score -1):

If it's a global variable you can use

```
v = [ globals()[i] for i in ['a', 'b', 'c'] ]
```

For example...

```
a = 1                       
b = 2
c = 3

v = [ globals()[i] for i in ['a','b','c'] ]

print(v)
>>>[1, 2, 3]
```

If it's a local variable in the code block for a separate function/class you can use `locals` instead. Of course, as mentioned in the comments you should avoid this scenario at all costs in the first place.

Comment: You should test before post the result. 1. there is an error on your code. This is what you expected to do `[globals()[i] for i in ['q', 'w', 'e']]`. 2. Anyway, this approach raises an exception.

Comment: Thanks - fixed the code. @MauroBaraldi that's interesting, I don't get one when I try to `print(v)`. What kind of exception?

Comment: Run this code and you will see!

Comment: I did! My output is just as in my response...when you tried it did you have 'q' 'w' 'e' initialized first?